# Populate() isn't reentrant Django Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, google-app-engine, firebase

I'm running google app engine, python 2.7, and importing Django 1.8. After pulling in python-firebase (-e git://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase.git#egg=python-firebase), I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
obj = __import__(path[0])
   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~trac-us/1.392706776803493304/main.py", line 25, in <module>
application = django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()
   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~trac-us/1.392706776803493304/libs/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
django.setup()
   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~trac-us/1.392706776803493304/libs/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~trac-us/1.392706776803493304/libs/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
  RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Many of the other solutions have suggested to alter the wsgi.py file, because django gets installed right before deployment in the requirements.txt file.

Ultimately this leads to the server stating: "Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds." How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and removing the database configuration for a sqlite database connection fixed this for me. Issue might've been that the sqlite library that django is looking for underneath was not present and thus, removing the sqlite configuration fixed that for me. pff, I was not using sqlite in that project any way.

However, as per a google groups thread I landed on, the error:

```
raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
  RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

is caused when one of the application that you're trying to load leads to an error within, which leads to this. I'll provide a link to the thread here, and although it's different from your problem(you probably solved it already), you might still find it useful:

[Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/X3Upsk9Wfsw) to groups thread

[The answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/modwsgi/X3Upsk9Wfsw/xPi4XJqCqXoJ) I was talking about

Hope you find it useful.